# ¿No es correcto decir "Al oso le ha siempre encantado la miel"?

Tags: sintaxis, orden-de-palabras, pretérito-perfecto

¿No es correcto decir?:

> Al oso le ha **siempre** encantado la miel.

¿O debería decir?:

> Al oso **siempre** le ha encantado la miel.

Comment: la primera me suena raro, pero no sé si está admitida

Answer (score 8):

Entre el verbo auxiliar y el participio se pueden insertar ciertos adverbios (como *siempre* y *nunca* y sobre todo cuantificadores como *casi* y *medio*). También se puede insertar el sujeto y pronombres de objeto y hasta invertir el orden (participio primero, auxiliar después), aunque esto último es muy poco común en el español moderno. (Ver: *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*, [§23.1k](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGKfIkTPYzCsTKZt) y sus referencias.)

Así que las dos alternativas son correctas. En este caso yo elegiría la forma con el auxiliar y el participio uno junto al otro: *Al oso siempre le ha encantado la miel.* Pero es una elección personal. Un escritor o un poeta pueden preferir cambiar el orden para que la oración tenga un ritmo diferente.