# Cuántas palabras se pueden introducir en medio de perífrasis verbales y tiempos compuestos

Tags: gramática, orden-de-palabras

Anteriormente no sabía de que se puede introducir algo en medio de tiempos compuestos. Solo pensaba en que es posible introducir algo en medio de perífrasis verbales ("*voy **ahora** a preguntar*", "*Iban **progresivamente** disminuyendo*", etc.) Pero leí las siguientes cadenas y por lo general entendí:

[¿Hay alguna regla para la posición del adverbio en una frase?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20266/23475)

[¿No es correcto decir "Al oso le ha siempre encantado la miel"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33235/23475)

No obstante, ¿cuantás palabras es posible introducir en medio de perífrasis verbales y tiempos compuestos? ¿Cuál es el límite de la cantidad de palabras? Por ejemplo, encontré una oración en Linguee:

"*Aún tengo **muchas cosas** que hacer, pero estoy muy agradecido por todas las oportunidades olímpicas que he tenido.*"

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿tiene algo que ver tu pregunta con un parser?

Comment: @Leo no, no tiene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hablemos de los tiempos compuestos. No existe una regla sobre la cantidad de cosas que se pueden introducir entre el auxiliar y el participio. En la práctica rara vez se encuentra más de un adverbio o frase adverbial corta en ese lugar. Es una decisión personal y estética usar este lugar. Uno puede decir:

- “Yo le había repetida, vehemente e insistentemente pedido que no viniera.”
- “Ella no le habría jamás de los jamases, ni en sueños, pedido que viniera.”

Estas frases están gramaticalmente bien, pero suenan un poco pomposas; en particular, la segunda es algo que sólo esperaría encontrar en una obra literaria, no en una conversación. La primera es más razonable porque en español es habitual coordinar de esta manera una serie de adverbios en *-mente*.

En las perífrasis verbales como el presente progresivo y similares tenemos una mayor libertad, ya que no son unidades tan cerradas como los tiempos compuestos:

- “Estaba simplemente y sin ninguna mala intención buscando un libro.”
- “Vamos, ahora sí por fin, y tras muchos tropiezos y desvíos innecesarios, llegando al final de la historia.”

Nótese cómo el ritmo de la frase hace necesario marcar pausas, indicadas por comas, en algunos lugares, lo cual no interrumpe la perífrasis. De todas formas, hay un punto en que uno debe dejar de meter cosas entre las partes de la perífrasis ya que el hablante va a perder el hilo. De nuevo, es una decisión personal y estética.

“Tener cosas que hacer” es una frase casi fija; se puede reemplazar “cosas” por “tareas” y algunos otros sinónimos, se le puede añadir algún adjetivo a las “cosas” y algún adverbio después de “tener”, pero eso es todo. Un ejemplo: “He tenido, por desgracia, demasiadas cosas que hacer” (las comas son opcionales en mi opinión). Otras frases por el estilo siguen este mismo patrón:

- “Tengo aún una dura pelea que dar.”
- “Nos quedan todavía unas semanas para disfrutar.”
- “Hay probablemente muchísimos problemas por resolver.”