# Cómo combinar correctamente varios adverbios juntos en “Yo le había repetida, vehemente e insistentemente pedido..."

Tags: gramática, adverbios

En la cadena [Cuántas palabras se puede introducir en medio de perífrasis verbales y tiempos compuestos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35216/23475) hay una oración:

*“Yo le había repetida, vehe**mente** e insistentemente pedido que no viniera.”*

Yo sé que cuando van varios adverbios consecutivos juntos con el sufijo "-mente", solo el último  adverbio tiene que ser con "-mente". ¿Por eso la palabra "vehemente" no tiene que ser también corta (tal como la palabra "repetida")?

¿O el sufijo "-mente" presenta ahí solamente porque no hay una corta palabra similar al "vehemente" (algún adjetivo, como en caso de "lentamente -> lento")?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Comment: Yo le había repetido, no repetida

Comment: @Iria No, "había" se refiere a "pedido".

Comment: No me suena bien por muchos sitios, a ver, analizamos "Yo le había repetida, vehemente e insistentemente pedido que no viniera. ", Yo es el sujeto, el verbo es había pedido, entonces, repetida es repetidamente, pero como vehemente no es adverbio modal como insistentemente, o repetidamente, pues cortas, rompes la unidad de la frase

Comment: y esto se debe a que como ya te han explicado en respuesta (por eso no hago yo una), vehemente no es adverbio sino adjetivo, o sea, que tienes varios errores debido a que vehemente no es adverbio

Comment: @Iria pero parece que al principio debería ser "vehementemente" y por eso se convirtió en "vehemente".

Comment: hay algo que no me suena bien, no doy con ello pero no me suena bien, de donde has sacado la frase? Igual es solo que los tres adverbios  modales son muchos (muy largos) y se pierde el sentido a la frase, pero hay algo que no me suena bien

Comment: @Iria De esta cadena https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35216/23475. Pero no sé de que fuente va esta frase desde el principio. Podría ser de alguna obra literaria.

Comment: La frase es correcta, pero efectivamente (como dice en la respuesta a la otra pregunta) no suena natural porque el verbo está muy lejos del auxiliar. Más natural sería "Yo le había pedido repetida, vehemente e insistentemente que no viniera".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vehemente](https://dle.rae.es/vehemente) no es un adverbio, sino un adjetivo que que casualmente termina en *-mente*. Esta terminación no es el sufijo *-mente* que significa "de manera".

De hecho, el adverbio derivado de *vehemente* es [vehementemente](https://dle.rae.es/vehementemente), aunque sospecho que no es usado muy frecuentemente debido a la cacofonía. Probablemente es más común el uso de "con vehemencia" o "de manera vehemente", que suenan mejor.

Comment: Ahora entiendo. Y debido a que vehemente va en la única forma como adjetivo (no se puede decir "vehemento, vehementa") esa palabra no se cambió. Como en ejemplo de Linguee: "Seguimos considerando que el proceso del estatuto debería continuar constante y rápidamente".

Comment: @Alex exactamente.

Comment: dicho lo cual, la omisión de los _-mente_ anteriores al último creo que es opcional y tal vez sí sería válido mostrar el penúltimo y el último solamente. No he podido encontrar referencias más que de la _opcionalidad_ de quitarlos.