# En adverbios con "-mente" que están coordinados, ¿puede elidirse el "-mente" de solamente algunos o si se elide debe ser en todos menos el último?

Tags: gramática, adverbios

En la [Nueva Gramática](https://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica) de la RAE, artículo [*7.14 La derivación adverbial. Propiedades morfológicas de los adverbios en *-mente**](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=feWzXJkDtNXCWhVY) (y páginas siguientes [1](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KekXaxOCyLJQVNJz) y [2](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KuHokOdZFURWdSLh)) leo:

> 7.14e A los argumentos que se mencionaron en el apartado anterior suele agregarse la capacidad que posee *-mente* de elidirse en los grupos coordinados de dos adverbios que ontienen esta terminación, como en *lisa y llanamente*. La elisión era infrecuente en la lengua medieval, pero se daba ya en la clásica y es común en la actual, sobre todo en la escrita.

Es decir, indica que dos adverbios terminados en *-mente* pueden combinarse de manera que en el primero se elida la terminación:

- Comieron rápida<strike>mente</strike> y alegremente.

Sin embargo, al hilo de [otra pregunta en el sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35224/1674) me surgió la duda: ¿cómo se combina si son más de uno? ¿Sería incorrecto elidir solamente algunos?

Es decir, ¿sería correcto lo siguiente?

- Comieron rápida<strike>mente</strike>, frugal**mente** y alegremente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que es una cuestión de estilo, que el manual se refiere a una pauta de recomendación que aplica para grupos (dos o más expresiones) para los que se propone "*la elipsis del segmento -mente*", dejando un sólo subfijo adverbial para todos ellos. En el manual RAE se ve que los ejemplos propuestos son simples y de dos adjetivos coordinados, para ilustrar el principio con claridad.

A la pregunta específica, siendo que el Manual de la Nueva Gramática alude a "*[la capacidad que posee -mente* de elidirse en los grupos coordinados](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KekXaxOCyLJQVNJz) de dos adverbios"; se entiende eso como algo no **obligatorio**, sino posible (sugerido) para omitir la repetición del sufijo en adjetivos coordinados.  Por lo tanto,  que una frase no siga esa recomendación, no la tornaría incorrecta desde el punto de vista gramatical; aunque si contraria a un mejor uso, en procura de una economía y armonía sonora de la escritura.

Tal como [se puede leer](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kAP3OLKeeLgJ:https://es.scribd.com/doc/167134332/58298244-Larousse-Gramatica-de-La-Lengua-Espanola%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ar&client=firefox-b-d) en el [Diccionario Larousse, Gramatica de La Lengua Española](https://www.scribd.com/doc/167134332/58298244-Larousse-Gramatica-de-La-Lengua-Espanola), (que reproduzco debajo) **la razón de esa omisión es evitar la [cacofonía](https://dle.rae.es/cacofon%C3%ADa)**, (o la `Disonancia que resulta de la inarmónica combinación de los elementos acústicos de la palabra.`
)

> *En general, es posible formar adverbios en -mente a partir de cualquier adjetivo calificativo, excepto de los gentilicios, de los que se refieren a colores y de adjetivos que denotan características o cualidades físicas que no admitirían una interpretación modal; sin embargo, en ciertos contextos pueden encontrarse: hawaianamente, argentinamente, blancamente, ..., de adjetivos como gordo, ..., delgado, peludo, no es común la formación de adverbios.  Cuando se coordinan dos adverbios terminados en -mente, **en el primero se omite el morfema para evitar la cacofonía,** es decir, se emplean formas sincopádas: atrevida y audazmente, lenta y cuidadosamente, tierna y amorosamente*

Esta entrada hace explicita mención a "**grupos coordinados**", con lo que se deduce que el agrupamiento puede contener más de dos:

[image: regla de omisión]

A propósito de ésto último he encontrado este texto, (en un manual de escritura, [en la página 53](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/71528955.pdf)) que refiere a la cacofonía como enemiga de la ***armonía eufónica.***

Comment: Gracias por la investigación exhaustiva. Sigue sin haber respuesta explícita a lo que pregunto, pero creo que el concepto de _evitar la cacofonía_ es suficientemente explícito como para pensar que lo correcto es elidir en todos menos el último.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando son más de uno, se hace exactamente lo mismo.
No lo digo por mi conocimiento de las normas de la RAE. Solo basado en mi experiencia como castellano hablante.

En el caso de tu ejemplo:

- Comieron rápida, frugal y alegremente.

Comment: Sí, lo sé. La duda es si lo que yo sugiero es posible también o no

Comment: Es posible pero incorrecto.