# Why is it "fácil y rápidamente" instead of "fácilmente y rápidamente"?

Tags: adverbios

I read this: "Conectarlo al cargador fácil y rápidamente sin dejarlo desprotegido." I also translated "easily and quickly" from English to Spanish on multiple online translators (SpanishDict, Google Translate, etc.), and they all say "fácil y rápidamente." Why is it not "fácilmente y rápidamente"?

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [En adverbios con "-mente" que están coordinados, ¿puede elidirse el -mente" de solamente algunos o si se elide debe ser en todos menos el último?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35229/6915).

Comment: Because in Spanish, if you have two adverbs with mente, you do not need to write mente for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas opciones son correctas, aunque la expresión "**fácil y rápidamente**" es un poco más común y suena más natural en algunas situaciones.

En general, el adverbio, "**fácilmente"** se utiliza para describir la facilidad con la que se realiza una acción, mientras que "**rápidamente**" se utiliza para describir la velocidad con la que se realiza dicha acción. Por lo tanto, si se quiere enfatizar la facilidad con la que se realiza algo, la expresión "**fácilmente y rápidamente**" podría ser una opción conveniente.

**Sin embargo, si se quiere simplemente describir cómo se realiza algo de manera fácil y rápida, "fácil y rápidamente" puede ser una expresión más adecuada.**

En resumen, ambas expresiones son correctas, y la elección entre ellas dependerá del contexto y de lo que se quiera enfatizar en la descripción de la acción.

**P.D.** En español en este tipo de frases, sobrentendemos el sufijo "*-mente*" aunque la primera palabra no lo introduzca, ya que es un modo de economizar el lenguaje tanto oral como escrito, ya que no suele alterar su significado.